# seqgranularity in TraMineRExtras

Tags: sequence, traminer

I am using the `seqgranularity` command in `TraMineRExtras`. I read in the help documentation that I can indicate `method = "mostfreq"`. What happens if, for example, I move from monthly to yearly data and in the 12 months I have 6 months in a state and 6 months in another state? Which of the two will be used to define the yearly sequences?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent category is identified by applying `which.max` on the outcome of `seqistatd`, which returns the state frequencies in the order of the alphabet. `which.max` returns the index of the first encountered maximum. Therefore, with `method="mostfreq"`, `seqgranularity` assigns the category that appears first in the alphabet among those that share the maximal frequency.

The example below with two sequences of length 24 shows how the outcome changes with the alphabet order

```
library(TraMineRextras)
dat <- read.table(text = "
                  a/6,b/6,c/2,d/10
                  b/6,a/6,c/10,d/2
                  ")
sdat <- seqformat(dat, from="SPS", to="STS", 
              SPS.in = list(xfix = "", sdsep = "/"), 
              stsep=",")

seq1 <- seqdef(sdat, alphabet=c("a","b","c","d")) 
## "a" precedes "b" in the alphabet
seqgranularity(seq1, method="mostfreq",tspan=12)
      
##   Sequence
## 1 a-d     
## 2 a-c 

seq2 <- seqdef(sdat, alphabet=c("d","c","b","a")) 
## Here "b" precedes "a" in the alphabet
seqgranularity(seq2, method="mostfreq",tspan=12)

##   Sequence
## 1 b-d     
## 2 b-c
```